# How do I pass the selected input value to a <p> tag using props and map method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a menu planner that is gonna go on a weekly basis. I am trying to pass the data from the forms to an empty array and from there to pass the data to a

tag in the lunch component. Problem is, when I submit the data I type gets posted on every single day and not the selected day. For example If I type on Sunday and add an entre, that entre gets posted every day of the week instead of just Sunday.  There is another component that passes the prop names. Other than that, it doesn't do anything.

```
const [meal, setMeal] = useState([]);

{week.map((day, i) => {
  const lunch = moment(day).format('dddd') + '_title';

  return (
    <Card>
      <Day
        key={i}
        id={i}
        titles={lunch}
        entres={meal.map((meals, index) => {return meals.entre})}
        onAdded={submitMeal}
        getCurrDates={day.getDate()}
        currMonths={moment(day).format('MMM')}
        dayNames={moment(day).format("dddd")}>
      </Day>
    </Card>
  );
})}
```

lunch component

```
const [lunch, setLunch] = useState({
  entre: "",
  side: ""
})

const handleChange = (e)=>{
  const {name, value} = e.target;
  setLunch(preLunchState =>{
    return {
      ...preLunchState,
      [name]: value
    }
  });
};

const submitLunch = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.onAdd(lunch);
  setLunch({
    entre: "",
    side: ""
  });
}

return (
  <div onChange={handleChange}>
    <h2>{props.dayName} <br/>{props.currMonth}  {props.getCurrDate}</h2>
    <h4>Lunch</h4>
    <form onSubmit={submitLunch}>
      <input placeholder='Entre'
        name='entre'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={lunch.entre}
        type='text'>
      </input>
      <textarea
        name="side"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={lunch.side}
        placeholder='Side' type='text'
      />
      <button type='submit' onClick={submitLunch}>x</button>
    </form>
    <div>{props.entre}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: We're going to need more details and context. Where does each set of code belong to? Where is the Lunch component being called? What props are passed into the Lunch component?